# Problem with one controller handling two forms (models)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have to implement this form, which at first seemed easy to me. For the models part, I created a one-to-many relationship between GeneralInformation and CourseList (very obvious). In the GeneralInformation I included the bottom section as well with the 'Comments', 'Remarks'etc.

The problem is that before submitting the General Information section, you fill the Course List which will give an error for the FK constraint (again, obvious). For the Course List I'm using DevExtreme datagrid.

The only solution I came up with is to create another table, which keeps the ID of GeneralInformation and each Course ID. A similar solution for many-to-many relationships. If this seems like a viable solution, then how do you store the IDs of Courses in the controller, and then the ID of GeneralInformation, to put them in the database. Now I think I'm handling two models with the same controller, which might not be an optimal solution or even against guidelines of .NET Core.

If someone has a better solution, it would be greatly appreciated.

[image: UI_demo]

Answer (score 1):

Your Model can be like this

```
public class Model_Name //enter your model name
{
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   public string LastName {get;set;}
   //other properties from General Information form
   public List<Course> Courses {get;set;} //Course is a separate model
   public string Remarks {get;set;}
}
```

In HTML do not map course to General info, Post the form and pass all the fields as json like below

```
{'FirstName':'Test','LastName':'Test','Courses':[{'Id':1}], 'Remarks':'test'}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're basically asking how to bind to a collection in a model.

Property binding would look like this:

```
<input asp-for="@Model.Collection[i].Property" />
```

What i did was store the course table (or grid) row as a partial view that takes an index as an argument with the course model and at the same time i maintain an index of the courses count using `data-id` attribute on each row and then every time a user wants to add a course i use ajax with the index of the last course as a parameter to fetch a new row rendered with an incremented index
and i append it to the table.
That way when your submit your form it will bind to a collection what ever the length is.